# connecting to a website from an android app

Tags: android

I am developing a simple android app that redirects to a particular website (for instance google) upon clicking on the 'start' button in my app home page. i have set the @id of my start button as 'bStart'. What should the coding be like in the method:

```
 start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ------------------
            ------------------
            ------------------
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       WebView webview = new WebView(classname.this);
       webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());       
       webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
       webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/"); 

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
    startActivity(launchBrowser);
```

or

```
    Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.co.uk"));
    startActivity(myWebLink);
```

Comment: Uri is working good.. did not try the second one.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.yourlinkhere.com");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

here is the code you want.hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is you want to open a website on click of a button.
Code to open a URL is:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can I have the entire code for such an application?? actually, i'm still in the process of learning, and I dont have much idea about stuffs.
Thank you.